# Google authentication (oauth2) (adonisJs+allyJs) Acount.google.com refused to connect

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, adonis.js

I have a Google auth connection on my web application that uses adonisJS allyjs  oauth2
to connect, I got this error with tow users recently, and I don't know where this error comes from

[image]

The user get this when he click on the button that redirect him to google auth page